# Can 'superior' alone have the schwa sound?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

The news caster pronounces ‘**superior**’ as /səˈpɪər i ər/.
And I can find his pronunciation in the [Random House Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/superior?s=t). But the other major dictionaries show /suːˈpɪriər/ or /sjuːˈpɪəriə/. So I can’t decide ‘superior’ alone can be pronounced /səˈpɪər i ər/, when it is pronounced by itself not in the sentence?

[[audio]](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/145)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is closely related to an [earlier question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3446/the-pronunciation-of-tremendous), which I think it would repay you to consult.

What is in play here is varying realizations and transcriptions of a *close rounded reduced vowel*: a vowel representing a stem <u> which is not only unstressed but 'bleached' of much of its distinctive character. For historical reasons, some dictionaries and phonologists represent this vowel with a schwa /ə/, others with /u/ or /ʊ/. (*I find it difficult to believe that anybody has ever pronounced this syllable with /uː/, unless under special circumstances requiring the syllable be unnaturally stressed.*) This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_vowels_in_English#Reduced_vowels_in_the_close_rounded_area) tells us the Oxford dictionaries are starting to use a symbol of their own, /ᵿ/, for this sound.

But it's not something anybody but a professional phonologist or phonetician needs to worry about. As long as you pronounce the syllable without stress, nobody will notice whether you say /sə/ or /sʊ/ or even /sɪ/; what people actually *hear* is the stressed vowels.

Comment: I am always amazed by the fact I’ve get much more what I expected. Thank you very much.