# How to pronounce "people"

Tags: nouns, pronunciation, vowels

I asked my English teacher about pronunciation of words like *table, available, apple* or *people*. He told me they end with a short A. But when I listen to native English speakers, I hear "pee-pole", which seems like a short O to me.

Comment: Its more like the 'u' in *pull* or *bull*

Comment: Any dictionary will tell you that *people* is pronounced `[ˈpʰiːpəl]`, sometimes written `[ˈpʰiːpl̩]`.

Comment: Listen: *people* Audio (US); Audio (UK) http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/people & try: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyl-TE8JJ8U (I've *not* checked the youtube link.)

Comment: @Jim Pronunciations vary.

Comment: From what I've observed, the schwa sound (ə) in this word (*people*) will sound closer to *pull* in AmE accents, and closer to *pole* in BrE. Being a non-native speaker, I know that the schwa can trouble us somewhat. I wrote an answer about this schwa sound specifically. I hope that you will find it useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14568/3281.

Comment: @DamkerngT. John Wells analyzes the (phonetic) syllabic [l̩] as a realization of the (phonemic) underlying string /əl/.  In other words, you may see /əl/ in a dictionary when no schwa sound is actually pronounced.  In this case, as an American English speaker, I don't pronounce a schwa, although other speakers may.

Comment: @snailboat (Oh, I forgot that! Thank you.) Instead of trying to add more information and might complicate things unnecessary, I will say that I completely agree with you. However, for the OP, you can use my observation above as additional information, especially if your first language is a syllable-timed one.

Answer (score 3):

The phonemic pronunciation of people is /ˈpi pəl/. So the first syllable is stressed, and the second is weaker (PEO-ple).

The upside-down "e" in the second syllable is called a *schwa*, and it represents a "neutral" vowel. The [Random House definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/schwa?s=t) of "schwa" gives as examples:

> the sound of *a* in *alone* and *sofa*, *e*  in *system*, *i*  in *easily*, *o*  in *gallop*, *u*  in *circus*.

The Cambridge Dictionaries online write this as /ˈpiː.pl̩/, indicating a much shorter vowel in the second syllable.

Comment: That is not an accurate IPA pronunciation. It’s closer to being a phonemic rendition, in which case you should use /slashes/ rather than [brackets].

Answer (score 1):

American and English pronunciations of the word *people*:

- [people](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/people_1?q=people#)

You can find pronunciations for the words *table*, *available* and *apple* at these links:

- [table](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/table_1?q=table#)
- [available](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/available?q=available#)
- [apple](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/apple?q=apple#)